# Get the Folder in which the index.php script is Php

Tags: php, .htaccess, dir

I am using `AltoRouter` to match routes for my php app. Apparently even if `index.php` is called, if the app is not in the domain root, you have to set `$router->setBasePath("/path/to/script");`

I need a function that collect the subfolder(if app is in subfolder).Eg if path is `/dir` and someone calls `www.domain.com/dir`, i can know its `/dir` and call `$router->setBasePath("/dir");`

Comment: Could you clarify? E.g. Where is the script executing? Would the base path of the current file be enough?

Comment: as @anubhava has put it in the answer below, i wanted to know the base directory where our .htaccess is being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]
```

This will set `${ENV:BASE}" to whatever sub-directory this .htaccess is residing in.

Then inside PHP you can use:

```
$_SERVER["BASE"]
```

which will be set to `/dir/` if .htaccess is in `/dir1/`.

Comment: what if the dirname is the root eg, `$thisDirectory = 'www'` yet in this situation we dont need to `->setBasepath()` or even worse its in `/dir/` but the domain maps to `/dir/` which in this case we also don need `->setBasePath`

Comment: If this is placed in `DocumentRoot` then `$_SERVER["BASE"]` will be `/`

Comment: Yes I have finally figured that out, If I could I could up the answer twice

Comment: This works if the URL is `/base/whatever/path` but not if the URL is `/base/index.php/whatever/path`. How can we ensure index.php is optional?

Comment: @TylersSN: Can you please open a new question for this.

Comment: @anubhava - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650151/dynamic-rewritebase-with-optional-index-php