# Dynamic RewriteBase with optional index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have dynamic base URLs at `/us/`, `/ca/` and `/fr-ca/`. Using the suggested RewriteCond as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25626489/1812580), I was able to get this to work in most cases. The cases that it works are when index.php is not included in the URL, so:

- /us/path/subpath
- /us/path2/subpath
- /us/path/subpath
- /us/path2/subpath

For each of these `$_SERVER['BASE']` will return `/us/`.

If my application plugs in `index.php` into the URL, `BASE` is no longer provided.

I've tried using `RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^((?:index.php/)?)([^#]*)#(.*)\1$`, but the entire URL is returned as `BASE`

**EDIT** I see now, that with `^` I am telling htaccess to expect index.php before /directory/. Continuing to dig in here.

**Edit 2**:

My virtual host document root points to `/var/www/html`. Within /var/www/html is a real directory called `us`. Directories `ca` and `fr-ca` are symlinks to `us`.

My htaccess rewrite ls:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]
```

Comment: You should include the conrete RewriteCond+rules in your question, not just link it. Also, is it possible that these aren't just virtual paths, but overlap with real directory structures? (If so: depends on the rewrite rules and conditions to take precedence over existing files.)

Comment: @anubhava - I've updated my post with an explanation of my setup. index.php exists within `/us/`

Comment: Yes. It is located in `/us/`

Comment: I'm dumping `$_SERVER`

Comment: `http://test.com/us/index.php/backend1912/some/other/stuff/without/file/extensions/`

Comment: I created a `/us/` directory inside site root then created a .htaccess inside it with just one rule as shown above. Inside `index.php` in same directory I get `$_SERVER["BASE"]` shown as `/us/`